Issue with border, tooltip values, and custom colors
I am trying to create a treemap chart using the highcharter package in R. The chart has some specific requirements:

Border on Level 2 Only: I want a visible border only on level 2 of the treemap.
Tooltip Values: The tooltip should display a specific value (Measure), but it's not showing up correctly.
Custom Colors Based on Group: I need to apply colors based on the Nome_Bloco grouping, which has specific hex values in the data. However, the colors are not displaying as expected.

Here is a sample of my data:
# Criando a amostra de dados
amostra_exemplo <- data.frame(
  Ano = rep(2020, 28),
  Nome_Bloco = c(
    "Ásia", "Europa", "Ásia", "Europa", "Europa", "América do Norte", "Ásia",
    "Europa", "Oriente Médio", "Ásia", "Europa", "Ásia", "Ásia", "Ásia", "Europa",
    "Ásia", "América do Norte", "África", "Europa", "Europa", "Ásia", "Ásia", "Europa",
    "Oriente Médio", "África", "América do Sul", "África", "Europa"
  ),
  Nome_Pais = c(
    "China", "Países Baixos", "Vietnã", "Espanha", "Turquia", "Estados Unidos",
    "Japão", "Alemanha", "Irã", "Tailândia", "Bélgica", "Paquistão", "Coreia do Sul",
    "Taiwan", "Itália", "Bangladesh", "México", "Egito", "Rússia", "Reino Unido",
    "Indonésia", "Malásia", "Portugal", "Arábia Saudita", "Argélia", "Argentina",
    "Marrocos", "França"
  ),
  Nome_ISIC_Secao = rep("Agropecuária", 28),
  US_FOB = c(
    22200, 1620, 1580, 1560, 1430, 1380, 1210, 1100, 991, 954, 937, 874, 827,
    782, 741, 703, 636, 632, 566, 517, 465, 387, 355, 326, 309, 263, 208, 182
  ),
  Peso_Liquido = c(
    62229888912, 4110577998, 5132048409, 5418399454, 2882562591, 704088313,
    5339672726, 534054772, 5112848300, 2665277397, 498422427, 1594134121, 
    3204474337, 3495261690, 1331952473, 1770877876, 2253802715, 3220588452, 
    1175860426, 1185890054, 484198841, 1431340194, 1363437379, 1235739572, 
    1274228344, 535504242, 1057032300, 160443867
  ),
  Cor = c(
    "#154360", "#8E44AD", "#154360", "#8E44AD", "#8E44AD", "#1F618D", "#154360",
    "#8E44AD", "#D35400", "#154360", "#8E44AD", "#154360", "#154360", "#154360",
    "#8E44AD", "#154360", "#1F618D", "#3F6129", "#8E44AD", "#8E44AD", "#154360",
    "#154360", "#8E44AD", "#D35400", "#3F6129", "#FFCC00", "#3F6129", "#8E44AD"
  )
)

# Exibindo a amostra
print(amostra_exemplo)


And here’s the code I’m using:
generate_treemap_country <- function(data, measure, year_filter, isic_filter, threshold = 0.1) {
  measure_column <- ifelse(measure == "value", "US_FOB", "Peso_Liquido")
  
  # Filtering and summarizing data
  treemap_data <- data %>%
    filter((Ano == year_filter | year_filter == "Todos") & 
           (Nome_ISIC_Secao == isic_filter | isic_filter == "Todos")) %>%
    group_by(Nome_Bloco, Nome_Pais, Cor) %>%
    summarise(Measure = sum(.data[[measure_column]], na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
  
  # Applying threshold and creating hierarchical data
  treemap_data <- treemap_data %>%
    mutate(Percent = Measure / sum(Measure) * 100) %>%
    mutate(Nome_Pais = ifelse(Percent < threshold, "Outros", Nome_Pais)) %>%
    group_by(Nome_Bloco, Nome_Pais, Cor) %>%
    summarise(Measure = sum(Measure), .groups = "drop")
  
  # Level options for the treemap
  lvl_opts <- list(
    list(level = 1, borderWidth = 0, borderColor = "transparent", dataLabels = list(
        enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}", style = list(color = "white", fontSize = "12px")
    )),
    list(level = 2, borderWidth = 1, borderColor = "white", colorVariation = list(key = "brightness", to = 0.5))
  )
  
  # Tooltip format
  tooltip_text <- ifelse(
    measure == "value",
    "<b>{point.name}</b> <br> <b>Valor Exportado</b>: US$ {point.Measure,.1f} mi",
    "<b>{point.name}</b> <br> <b>Peso Exportado</b>: {point.Measure:,.1f} toneladas"
  )
  
  # Creating treemap
  highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type = "treemap", layoutAlgorithm = 'squarified', backgroundColor = "#fff") %>%
    hc_add_series(
      name = "Measure", type = "treemap", allowTraversingTree = TRUE, levelIsConstant = FALSE,
      data = data_to_hierarchical(treemap_data, c("Nome_Bloco", "Nome_Pais"), "Measure"),
      allowDrillToNode = TRUE, levels = lvl_opts
    ) %>%
    hc_colors(treemap_data$Cor) %>%
    hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, pointFormat = tooltip_text) %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
}

# Running the function
generate_treemap_country(g_532, "value", 2020, "Agropecuária")




This doesn't fully answer your question, but try setting the tooltip_text to "{point.value}" instead of "{point.Measure}". Instead of hc_colors(), you can also directly pass your colors to the data_to_hierarchical() function, e.g., data_to_hierarchical(treemap_data, c("Nome_Bloco", "Nome_Pais"), "Measure", colors = unique(treemap_data$Cor)).

When you mention wanting to have a visible border only for level 2 of the treemap, do you mean you'd like to highlight the second layer of the chart?
To help clarify, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7nLjhsup/
Try changing the enabled value on line 19 to false—this will give you a better idea of what we refer to as level 2.
Or, if you're talking about the drilldown instead, we can totally handle it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pd6umytb/
